# Old school javascript not working in Chrome and IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

I need to solve a problem on an old system we still use. I am busy converting a new system to jquery but these nuggets from the old system sometimes pop up.

The code below works great in Firefox but doesn't work at all in Chrome or IE.

I have added a console.log("test") and this runs in Firefox but not in Chrome or IE.

Please let me know what's the best way to do this in vanilla javascript so it's cross browser friendly. Thanks

Code

```
function showlaptop(theTable)
{
  if (document.getElementById(theTable).style.display == 'none')
  {
        document.getElementById(theTable).style.display = 'block';
        console.log("test");
  }
}

function hidelaptop(theTable)
{
  if (document.getElementById(theTable).style.display == 'none')
  {
        document.getElementById(theTable).style.display = 'none';
  }
  else
  {
        document.getElementById(theTable).style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

Comment: The error does not appear to be in the code snippet you provided...

Comment: What error are you getting? Perhaps a value is being passed for `theTable`, that doesn't exist as an id on the page.

Comment: Does Chrome tell you the error if you open the console before you run the code? (Ctrl-shift-J) Also, the `hidelaptop()` function is doing the same thing in its if and else branches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work in all browsers...

```
function showlaptop(theTable)
{
  if (document.getElementById(theTable).style.display == 'none')
  {
        document.getElementById(theTable).style.display = '';
        console.log("test");
  }
}

function hidelaptop(theTable)
{
  if (document.getElementById(theTable).style.display == '')
  {
        document.getElementById(theTable).style.display = 'none';
  }
  else
  {
        document.getElementById(theTable).style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

that is, replace `'block'` with `''`

You do not need the second else BTW...

**UPDATE:**

As mentioned by Rob in the comments. The default display value for everything is not `'block'`, although, some browsers allow it, but those that follow the standards will not render the page accordingly...

Comment: Is there any particular reason explicitly setting `display` to `block` would fail? I seem to remember that being the default, but never an issue with outright stating it.

Comment: Because the [default display value](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html) for a table element is `table`, not `block`. However, some browsers don't suppor the standard values and will not show any error, but those that stick to the standard will.